# How do i find out dll dependencies of a Cygwin program?

Tags: dll, cygwin

Given a Cygwin executable, how do i find out all the dll's that it depends upon?
For the libraries that are loaded by the system executable loader i can use a tool like `depends` (aka Dependency Walker), but i have no idea how to trace the dll's that the program tries to load dynamically with Load Library.

My aim is to be able to take the minimal dependencies of a program built for Cygwin platform in order to make it work portable, without all the Cygwin stuff that it is never gonna use (some base command line utils, man pages etc.).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Lockhart, the solution is simply to cygcheck the executable. Here are some references: on [Wordpress](https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/finding-dlls-used-by-a-cygwin-program/) and [his site](https://milosophical.me/blog/2007/03/09/finding-dlls-used-by-a-cygwin-program.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30548809)